# Problem with spell checking packages in R

Tags: r, spell-checking, hunspell

I'm trying to check spelling some words in Russian using "hunspell" library in R.

```
bad_words <- hunspell("Язвенная болзень", dict='ru_RU.dic')
```

I have installed Russian dictionary, from here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/hunspell-ru/
It has encoding UTF-8. However, I have following error:

Failed to convert line 1 to ISO8859-1 encoding. Try spelling with a UTF8 dictionary.

It seems strange, neither dict nor R file don't have encoding ISO8859-1...
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are operating on Windows, my first guess would be that this is related to the lack of native UTF-8 support in R on Windows.  This will be resolved when R4.2 is released; you might wish to try using the [development release](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rdevel.html) and seeing whether the problem persists.

Another thing to check is whether your `DESCRIPTION` file contains the line `Encoding: UTF-8`, such that your source files are treated as having this encoding.